# Remove all rows based on a threshold in R

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I want to remove every row that has a number above 6 and below -6. In other words, if a row has at least one number that is not between -6 and 6 I want that row removed.

As a reproducible example, consider:

```
set.seed(0); mat <- matrix(sample(-7:7,24,replace=TRUE), ncol = 4)
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    6    6   -5    7
#[2,]   -4    7    3   -2
#[3,]   -2    2   -2    4
#[4,]    1    2    4    7
#[5,]    6   -7    0   -4
#[6,]   -4   -4    3    2
```

I want

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   -2    2   -2    4
#[2,]   -4   -4    3    2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you matrix is `mat`, you can get row ID that meet your requirement via either of the two:

```
id <- which(apply(mat, 1, function (x) all(abs(x) <= 6)))
id <- which(rowSums(abs(mat) > 6) < 1)
```

Now you extract / retain those rows to get a new matrix:

```
new_mat <- mat[id, ]
```

**Example**

```
set.seed(0); mat <- matrix(sample(-7:7,24,replace=TRUE), ncol = 4)
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    6    6   -5    7
#[2,]   -4    7    3   -2
#[3,]   -2    2   -2    4
#[4,]    1    2    4    7
#[5,]    6   -7    0   -4
#[6,]   -4   -4    3    2
```

My code gives:

```
new_mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   -2    2   -2    4
#[2,]   -4   -4    3    2
```